# What is the correct way to reuse code in any team-based (work) project?

Tags: c#, reusability, code-reuse

So while I was working, a colleague of mine (code-)reviewed my code (shown below). The code is edited a little bit so it doesn't show what it's about.

```
//Types is a static class with static strings (because enums cant be strings)
//id can be the id of two different subjects
var data = GetFromDb(Types.Type, id);

GetFromDb(string type, int id){
    string filter = GetFilter(type);

    db.Query(SELECT * FROM WHERE filter=id)
}
```

---

The idea behind this code is, that it can be used for two different subjects. Let's say for getting the details of an invoice and an order. The `GetFilter()` method changes the filter based on what type (invoice or order) we're after. The db query is nearly identical.

According to my colleague, **having two nullable parameters instead of giving a type parameter would be better for the reusability and readability of the code.**

---

**My question is** (quite obviously): which method is better and what are the golden rules of code reusability?

P.S. Keep in mind that I'm a Junior (.NET) programmer. I'm trying to learn more concepts to good programming, but the internet is far too misleading, hence the question now on StackOverflow.

Comment: This question *might* be better suited for the [Software Engineering Stack Exchange](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Best check their [*What topics can I ask about here?*](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) page first though.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say code reusability is a nice goal to aim for, but not necessarily always the best solution.

It would make sense to reuse a method if it is logic-heavy and/or heavily unit tested, but for a simple method like the one you give in the example, it's not as important.

One rule of thumb I keep in mind is that if you find yourself coding the same thing more than twice, see if you can reuse it.

Another is that for the long term, project independency trumps code-reuse.  So, rather duplicate code than add too many relations between your projects (talking in C# terms here).

Regarding your original question: It's a bit hard to understand the code-example since sensitive data has been removed, but I think I would be tempted to just write two methods, for readability.